# Show That $A - B = A \cap B^c$ and Hence Simplify the Following Using the Laws of Set Algebra.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Show that $A - B = A \cap B^c$ and hence simplify the following using the laws of set algebra.
>
> a) $A \cap (A - B)$
>
> b) $(A - B) \cup (A \cap B)$
>
> c) $(A \cup B) \cup (C \cap A) \cup (A \cap B)^c$

I wasn't at all sure how to show that $A - B = A \cap B^c$, so I have no attempt for that one.

Note that I've mentioned the set laws used for each step, to ensure that I understand what's going on.

**a)**

$A \cap (A - B)= (A \cap A) - B$ *(By the law of distributivity.)*

$= A - B$ *(By the idempotence.)*

$= A - B$ $\ \ \ Q.E.D.$

**b)**

$(A - B) \cup (A \cap B) = A - (B \cup (A \cap B))$ *(By associativity.)*

$= A - (B \cup A) \cap (B \cup B)$ *(By distributivity.)*

$= A - (B \cup A) \cap B$ *(By idempotence.)*

$= (A - B) \cup (A \cap B)$ *(By associativity.)*

$= (A - B) \cup (B \cap A)$ *(By commutativity.)*

$= A - (B \cup B) \cap A$ *(By associativity.)*

$= A - B \cap A$ *(By idempotence.)*

$= A - A \cap B$ *(By commutativity.)*

$= \emptyset \cap B$

$= \emptyset$ *(By domination.)*

**But the solutions say that this should be $B$.**

**c)**

$(A \cup B) \cup (C \cup A) \cup (A \cap B) = (A \cup B) \cup (C \cap A) \cup (A \cap B)^c = (A \cup B) \cup (C \cap A) \cup A^c \cup B^c$

$= (A \cup B) \cup (C \cup A^c) \cap (A \cup A^c) \cup B^c$ *(By De Morgan's law.)*

$= (A \cup B) \cup (C \cup A^c) \cap (A \cup A^c)$ *(By distributivity.)*

$= (A \cup B) \cup (C \cup A^c) \cap U \cup B^c$ *(By union with complement.)*

$= (A \cup B) \cup (C \cup A^c) \cap U$ *(By domination.)*

$= (A \cup B) \cup ((C \cup U) \cup (A^c \cap U))$ *(By distributivity.)*

$= (A \cup B) \cup (C \cup A^c)$ *(By identity laws.)*

$= (A \cup B \cup C) \cup A^c$ *(By associativity.)*

$= U$ *(Assuming $A$, $B$, $C$ are the only sets in our universe.)* $\ \ \ Q.E.D.$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my work and demonstrate the parts that I wasn't able to do.

Comment: Write down the definition of $A-B$.

Comment: For b), is the associativity applicable in your first line?

Comment: Technically, by the laws of *set* algebra, the complement $B^c$ of a set does not exist.

Comment: @xbh $A - B = \{ x | x \in A, x \not\in B \}$

Comment: @xbh $(A - B) \cup (A \cap B) = A - (B \cup (A \cap B))$ Please elaborate.

Comment: @ThePointer Use and $A \subset B $and $ A \supset B \iff A=B$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path What do you mean?

Comment: @xbh Can you please demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: @ThePointer What is associativity law according to your text?

Comment: $(A \cup B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$

Comment: @ThePointer Are you sure? This is distributivity as I learned...

Comment: If I let $A - B = C$, then can I not use associativity such that we get $(C \cup A) \cap (C \cup B)$?

Comment: @xbh Oh, of course. My apologies, I mixed it up for a moment.

Comment: @xbh Associativity: $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup C$

Comment: @ThePointer Sorry, no. Associativity is specifically stated for *one* operation.

Comment: Maybe you should review about those laws of set algebra. You are kind of rushing into questions. Concepts are always important.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Yeah, but the complement dose not require the law of set algebra only.

Comment: @xbh What I did was I let $C = A - B$ so that ... Oh wait .... $(C) \cup (A \cap B) = (C \cup A) \cap (C \cap B) \not= A - (B \cup (A \cap B))$

Comment: Ok, I see what I did wrong now. Can you please demonstrate how the proof for $A - B = A \cap B^c$ and b) is done so I have a reference?

Comment: @ThePointer How do your text prove $A=B$? Imitate this process.

Comment: @xbh $A - B = \{ x | x \in A, x \not\in B \}$. Let $x \in A - B$. Therefore, $x \in A$ and $x \not\in B$. Therefore, $x \in \{  x | x \in A, x \not\ B \} = A \cap B^c$. Therefore $A - B \subseteq A \cap B^c$. Is that correct for the first half?

Comment: @ThePointer Right. Now for the other half, do the same thing.

Comment: @xbh Ok, thanks for the direction. $A \cap B^c = \{ x | x \in A\} \cap \{y | y \not\in B \} = \{ w | w \in A, w \not\in B \}$. Let $w \in A \cap B^c$. Therefore, $w \in  \{ w | w \in A, w \not\in B \} = \{ x | x \in A, x \not\in B\} = A - B$. Therefore, $A \cap B^c \subseteq A - B$. Correct?

Comment: @ThePointer Yeah.